# Why I get error "Abort loadExtensionAsync"

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, viewer

I trust initialization load two model in my viewer. For this I create two viewer and add for they html container where they initializing. Both of that model have itself toolbar. All is good, but some toolbar extensions don't loaded in viewers. 
I use this code in 6 version and all working good, but in 7 version I get this error list.
This is image of console errors of browser.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79UmW.png)

```
This is stack trace error.
ExtensionManager.js:399 
Uncaught (in promise) Abort loadExtensionAsync('Autodesk.ViewCubeUi')
(anonymous) @   ExtensionManager.js:399
c.onload    @   load-dependency.js:51
load (async)        
o   @   load-dependency.js:53
(anonymous) @   ExtensionManager.js:394
loadExtensionAsync  @   ExtensionManager.js:393
loadExtension   @   ExtensionManager.js:238
(anonymous) @   GuiViewer3D.js:445
setTimeout (async)      
L.createUI  @   GuiViewer3D.js:430
(anonymous) @   GuiViewer3D.js:276
(anonymous) @   GuiViewer3D.js:288
setTimeout (async)      
(anonymous) @   GuiViewer3D.js:283
p   @   Viewer3D.js:1199
(anonymous) @   SvfLoader.js:251
i   @   WorkerCreator.js:182
```

This is my code, which initializing two viewer and loaded two model.

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function (){
  var htmlDiv = document.getElementById('MyViewerDiv');
  var htmlDivSecond = document.getElementById('MySecondViewerDiv');

  viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv, config3d);
  viewerSecond = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDivSecond, config3dSecond);

  var startedCode = viewer.start();
  if(startedCode > 0){
    console.error('Faild to create a Viewer: WebGl not supported.');
    return;
  }
  Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId,onDocumentLoadSuccess,onDocumentLoadFailure );
  console.log('Initialization ....');
  Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId1,onDocumentLoadSuccess1,onDocumentLoadFailure1 );
});
```

...

```
function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
   console.log(doc);
    var defaultModel = doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
    viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, defaultModel);
    // Choose any of the avialble viewables
    var svfUrl = doc.getViewablePath();

    viewerSecond.start(svfUrl, onLoadModelSuccess, onLoadModelError);
}
```

I will be very grateful for your help.

Comment: Can confirm to be able to reproduce the issue ... checking with our Engineering for comments and will get back soon

Comment: I checked and see this problem again. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Engineering has acted quickly and fix the issue - see [here](https://output.jsbin.com/pimelon/) and [here](https://jsbin.com/pimelon/edit?html,js) that all extensions load fine with dual Viewer instances:

[image]

```
const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('MyViewerDiv'));
  const viewerSecond = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('MyViewerDiv2'));
```

Comment: I very very grateful.